# Why gcc's output much slower than Visual Studio's (for this code)?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-2012

When I compile the followning code on a regularly updated Ubuntu 16.04 64bit using gcc by

```
gcc source.c -O3 --fast-math
```

the executable file takes about 45 seconds of CPU time to run. But on the same machine and in Windows 7 64bit, using Visual Studio 2012 in release mode, it takes less than 10 seconds of CPU time to run. What is the main cause of this difference? Haven't I used enough optimization options of gcc? Is Visual Studio's compiler a better one? Or something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define Nx 1000

int main()
{
    double d = 0.015e-2;        // meter
    double V0 = 400;            // volt
    double De = 1800e-4;        // m^2 per sec
    double mu_e = 2.9e1 / 760;  // m^2 per volt sec
    double n0 = 1e19;           // per m^3
    double e_eps = 1.602e-19 / 8.854e-12;
    double ne[Nx], je[Nx], E[Nx];
    double dx = d / (Nx - 1);
    double dt = 1e-14;          // s
    const int Nt = 500000;
    int i, k;
    double sum;
    FILE *fp_ne, *fp_E;
    double alpha, exp_alpha, R;
    int ESign = -1;
    clock_t start_t, end_t;

    start_t = clock();
    // initialization
    for (i = 1; i < Nx; i++)
        ne[i] = n0;
    ne[0] = 1e-4 * n0;

    for (i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
        E[i] = -V0 / d;

    // time loop
    for (k = 0; k < Nt; k++)
    {
        if (k%1000==0) printf("k = %d\n", k);
        for (i = 0; i < (Nx-1); i++)
        {
            alpha = mu_e*dx*E[i]/De;
            exp_alpha = exp(alpha);
            R = (exp_alpha-1)/alpha;
            je[i] = (De/(dx*R))*(ne[i]-exp_alpha*ne[i+1]);
        }

        for (i = 1; i < (Nx - 1); i++)
            ne[i] += -dt/dx*(je[i] - je[i-1]);
        ne[Nx - 1] = ne[Nx - 2];

        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < (Nx - 1); i++)
            sum += dx*je[i];
        for (i = 0; i < (Nx - 1); i++)
        {
            E[i] += -dt*e_eps*(sum / d - je[i]);
            if (E[i]>=0) ESign=+1;
        }
        if (ESign==1) break;
    }

    // output
    printf("time=%e\n",k*dt);
    fp_ne = fopen("ne.txt", "w");
    fp_E = fopen("E.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp_ne, "# x (cm)\tne(per cm^3)\n");
    fprintf(fp_E,  "# x (cm)\tE(V/cm)\n");
    for (i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
        fprintf(fp_ne, "%f\t%e\n", i*dx*100,ne[i]/1e6);
    for (i = 0; i < Nx-1; i++)
        fprintf(fp_E, "%f\t%e\n", i*dx*100, fabs(E[i])/1e2);
    fclose(fp_ne);
    fclose(fp_E);
    end_t = clock();
    printf("CPU time = %f\n", (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Comment: Profile both and compare?  I have no idea what this code does, and I have no answer.  It has 'meter', 'volt' and the electronic charge in it, so it's some physics, electromagnetic thingy, and I don't want to take it apart to find out.  What do you expect us to do with it, exactly?

Comment: Oh - and it reads data files with some stuff in them,  Again, what are we supposed to do with this?  Is the app I/O bound?  How big are the files?  You know all this stuff, so you should do [whatever]

Comment: Compare generated code (math part only) I/O and another library functions can be completely different.

Comment: the biggest time taker is the output to the terminal (in Ubuntu linux 16.04)   For me on my machine, 21+ seconds to output all the data

Comment: are you running each of the OSs directly on the machine/computer or is one of them running in a VM?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I did was comment out the in-loop I/O.

```
//if (k%1000==0) printf("k = %d\n", k);
```

*I obtained the below timings with only that change. The `fprintf` calls at the end do influence the timings significantly, but not their relative differences, so I'm not going to measure all of these again.*

I got these timings on my Arch Linux first-gen Core i5 (all compiled with the standard `-O2`):

- GCC 7.1:

  ```
  CPU time = 23.459520
  ```
- Clang 4.0.1:

  ```
  CPU time = 22.936315
  ```
- Intel 17.0.4:

  ```
  CPU time = 7.830828
  ```

On my Qemu/libvirt virtual machine of Windows 10 on that same machine I get these timings:

- MinGW-w64 GCC 6.3:

  ```
  CPU time = 76.122000
  ```
- VS 2015.3:

  ```
  CPU time = 13.497000
  ```
- VS 2017:

  ```
  CPU time = 49.306000
  ```

On WINE (native Linux, but Win32 API emulation, should still be comparable to native Linux code execution)

- MinGW-w64 GCC 6.3:

  ```
  CPU time = 56.074000
  ```
- VS 2015.3:

  ```
  CPU time = 12.048000
  ```
- VS 2017:

  ```
  CPU time = 34.541000
  ```

Long story short: it seems like these output the best code for this particular problem:

1. Intel on Linux (probably also on Windows)
2. VS 2015.3
3. GCC/Clang on Linux
4. VS 2017
5. MinGW-w64 GCC.

Looking at the assembly will be the only way to get to the bottom of this, but properly analysing that is beyond me.

Comment: Compare 32-bit mingw-w64 against 64-bit

Comment: Thanks. That `time=5.000000e-09` has nothing to do with the execution time. So you can omit it.

Comment: @M.M. I don't see how that makes any meaningful difference in the context of this question.

Comment: @rubenvb i think it'd be a useful data point if , say, it turned out 32-bit was slow and 64-bit matched the faster compilers

Comment: @rubenvb *I don't see how that makes any meaningful difference in the context of this question.* [32-bit x86 has 8 32-bit general purpose registers.  64-bit x86 has 16 64-bit general-purpose registers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#64-bit)  Doubling the number of available registers along with doubling the amount of data each register can hold certainly can have a huge performance impact.

Comment: @Andrew I never denied that it might have a performance impact. The OP compares 64-bit to 64-bit binaries, and so do I. The 32-bit data point will not help explain the observed difference (what the question is about) in any way.